# Interactive PHP shell techniques

Tags: php, command-line

This is a bit of a vague question I realise, but I've been looking around for interactive PHP shells that let me 'play' with classes, methods and data, such as those that come from a CodeIgniter application. The objective is to end up with something like Firebug, but for PHP.

I've had a look at the PHP shell created by Facebook (https://github.com/facebook/phpsh) and got this running locally, but I'd be interested to know if anyone is using this in anger, and what kind of techniques they use. I fully realise that JavaScript is a totally different animal (event driven for starters), but it seems like this should be possible.

I mention CodeIgniter because it has a [nicely defined entry point](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html) for command line sessions which seems like a good point to start.

Things that I would like to be able to do - interactively create sessions with authentication servers (google etc), interrogate data sources using php methods.. that kind of thing. For learning new web services, or data structures, it seems like it would accelerate massively the familiarisation process.

Is this a practical objective?

Comment: still looking for some ideas on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ability to rapidly prototype should be part of any programmer's toolbelt. Take a look at eval2- since putting it together years ago, I've found it to be handy enough.

See videos at http://eval2.sourceforge.net/videos.php